# exact word matches with different combinations from given query string in mysql full-text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, myisam

how to make myisam table to return results that are matching with different combination of words and nothing more extra from given search string.

I am using the following query on my tags table

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST('word1 word2'));
```

and the table might contain rows as follows

- 1 word1 word2 word3
- 2 word2 word3 word4
- 3 word1
- 4 word3 word2
- 5 word2
- 6 word2 word1
- 7 word1 word2
- 8 word3 word4

i need only the following rows as results

- 3 word1
- 5 word2
- 6 word2 word1
- 7 word1 word2

but the actual result i am getting is

- 1 word1 word2 word3
- 2 word2 word3 word4
- 3 word1
- 4 word3 word2
- 5 word2
- 6 word2 word1
- 7 word1 word2

how to achieve this??

I have tried boolean mode search with `+` but it makes that the words given `+` as compulsory in search results which is not what i want.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a late reply, yet, this will solve the issue. Use `IN BOOLEAN MODE` of MySQL FTS.

```
SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST('+word1 +word2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Take a look at [Full Text Boolean Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

> Note In implementing this feature, MySQL uses what is sometimes
>   referred to as implied Boolean logic, in which
>
> `+` stands for AND
>
> `-` stands for NOT
>
> `[no operator]` implies OR

Answer (score 0):

I don't think mysql FULLTEXT supports what you want. I could only get to do what you want with

```
SELECT * 
FROM tags 
where (name LIKE 'word1' OR name LIKE 'word2' OR name LIKE 'word1 word2' or name LIKE 'word2 word1') ;
```

Read more about fulltext here [mysql fulltext](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)